# Change display name on YouTube

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management

I use the same Google account for all Google products (YouTube, Drive, Analytics etc). For YouTube, I'd like to use a different profile name (eg my display name) but still have it linked to the same Google account so I don't have to login/logout of multiple accounts.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

**You can have only one name per Google account, however, YouTube allows you to use a "proxy" name if you connect your YouTube channel to Brand Account.**

> [image]
>
> **[https://support.google.com/youtube/](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2897336)**

Answer (score 0):

First move your channel to a brand account as described here https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en, brand account can have its own display name and url. Please note all the comments added with your personal account will be lost.

[image]